# Fast and Clean way to parse packets

Tags: c, linux

I have around 150 different types of packets having ids 0 - 149. Each packet has a corresponding parse function.
Whenever a packet arrives , I have to call its corresponding parse function.
As far as i know there are 3 good ways to do this

1. check opcodes and call functions inside 150 if-else conditions
2. 150 switch cases
3. an array of function pointers with packet id as the index

I don't have any memory constraints and server is also extremely fast.So wasting few CPU cycles is not much of an issue.

Is there a better way to do this ? If not, which of the above is the best method ?
NB : I am using C, not C++

Comment: "I don't have any memory constraints and server is also extremely fast." translates to "Who cares? Try something and see how it works out." A `switch` can probably do it, if not a regular expression of some kind.

Comment: It honestly sounds like the real problem here is not performance, but managing the complexity. If you can come up with a [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) model for this it'll make adding and removing cases much easier than bashing around with `if` statements and `switch` cases. Personally I'd steer towards having some light tooling that auto-generates some code based on a template so that as you add new cases the code gets rebuilt accordingly. A little bit of Python, Perl or Ruby can help here, or in a pinch, a support tool compiled in C.

Comment: Choice 3. has worked well -- simple, efficient, easily extended

Comment: I would go as @tadman said. In the past I did this using awk. Fast and easy

Answer (score 2):

> I will describe a way I did this in the past, to parse messages
> between Unix and a mainframe. It then seemed to be simple and easy to
> manage. Was used for years. Here I am just copying from parts of that code. Hope it can be useful

#### in short

In fact it is just an 8-line `awk` script **and** the mechanics around it. This article is just a description of the system that worked well for me and can be easily adapted: `awk` generates a very basic header file that links functions and ids, and it is integrated into the build process, so if we change something or add a new function it gets updated by itself. Why `awk`? well, I believe these `A`, `W` and `K` people are genuises and it works very very well with patterns. But I wrote this very same kind of .h file prodution for reference tables in C or C++ or java or Python also, when `awk` is not an option

#### how it works

I used a table of pointers to the functions and a simple annotation scheme on the source. For the sake of this example the functions are like `function_3()` below

```
// function_3 @packet-id 149
// function_3 @packet-id 0

int     function_3(Packet* p) // @packet-id 3
{
    printf("Hi from function_3(), id is %d\n", (int) p->id);
    return 0;
};
```

- The annotation is `@packet-id` in the same line as the function name, as in `function_3()` above
- When there is more than one id parsed by the same function I used a comment like

```
// function_3 @packet-id 149
```

often just before the function itself. In the case here `function_3()` will be called for packets with `id` 3, 149 and 0

#### calling the parsing function based on *packet id*

I used a call by id, like this

```
int     callById(const Id, const VFT*);
```

where `Id` is the message type and `VFT` is a reference table where the position `N` is the address of the function that parses Id `N`.

On startup a function

```
VFT*    build_VFT(const unsigned);
```

builds the array based on the annotations in the source code. I will post a small example below

#### structs for the example

```
typedef uint8_t Id;

typedef struct
{
    Id      id;
    void*   data;

}   Packet;

typedef int (*Packet_care)(Packet*);

typedef struct
{
    unsigned     nIds;
    Packet_care* fn;

}   VFT;   

int     function_1(Packet*); 
int     function_2(Packet*);
int     function_3(Packet*);

VFT*    build_VFT(const unsigned);
VFT*    delete_VFT(VFT*);
int     callById(const Id, const VFT*);
```

`Packet_care` is a pointer to a function that receives a pointer to a `Packet` and returns an `int`. My case was a bit more complex but the code here is just a test case, so I left here just the minimum: `Packet` here is just an `Id` and some data. `VFT` has just a counter and the table of pointers

#### Parsing the anotations

It is C and Linux here, so ***awk*** is not totally off-topic...

```
BEGIN       { found = 0 }
/@packet-id/{ 
       fName =  $2
       if ( fName ~ /\(/ )
       {
           fName = gensub( /(.+)\((.+)/, "\\1", 1, $2)
       }
       ref = 0
       for( i = 3; i < NF; i++)
       {
           if ($i ~ "@packet-id" )
           {
               ref = i+1
               i = NF + 1
           }
       }
       print ARRAY, "[", $ref, "] = ", fName, ";"
       found = found + 1
   }
END {   exit found    }
```

This could be written in C for sure, or any language, but `awk` was written for the same people that wrote C, at the same time, and used just for this sort of things. And it is so easy...

- the program just looks up for lines with the chosen annotation --- `@packet-id` here --- and take the next string as the `Id` number. ARRAY is an execution argument and gives the name of the Array in the `VFT` source. The output is just a table `F[ID] = N` where `F` is the name of the array, `ID` is the packet id and `N` is the function name.
- the script builds a file that is included in the compilation of the program. It is a one-line command. But I will show here a 1-line shell script that is easier to read:

```
 ./build_ref.sh test.h from vft.c using "vft->fn"
```

And it does just that: builds `"ref.h"` using the annotations on `"vft.c"` assuming that the `VFT` is declared as `vft` and the array of pointers is `fn[]`.

The single command inside the script is

```
awk -v ARRAY=${5} -f t.awk.sh ${3} > ${1}
```

just to make the ends meet.

#### a test run

```
Processing packets...

Will call function for packet id 0
Hi from function_3(), id is 0
function returned 0 for id 0

Will call function for packet id 1
Hi from function_1(), id is 1
function returned 0 for id 1

Will call function for packet id 2
Hi from function_2(), id is 2
function returned 0 for id 2

Will call function for packet id 3
Hi from function_3(), id is 3
function returned 0 for id 3
function returned -1 for id 4
function returned -1 for id 5

Will call function for packet id 149
Hi from function_3(), id is 149

Will call function for packet id 22
Hi from function_2(), id is 22

Will call function for packet id 12
Hi from function_2(), id is 12
```

#### here is main.c

```
#include "vft.h"
int main(void)
{
    VFT* vft = build_VFT(150);
    printf("\nProcessing packets...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i += 1)
        printf("function returned %d for id %d\n",
            callById( (Id) i, vft), i);

    callById(149,vft);
    callById(22,vft);
    callById(12,vft);
    vft = delete_VFT(vft);
    return 0;
};
```

A table is created and parser functions are called based on the Id. The table is drestroyed and the program ends

#### The table constructor

```
VFT*    build_VFT(const unsigned size)
{
    VFT* vft = (VFT*) malloc(sizeof(VFT));
    vft->nIds = size;
    vft->fn = (Packet_care*) malloc ( size*sizeof(Packet_care*) );
    for( int i=0; i<size; i+= 1) *(vft->fn + i) = NULL;
    #include "ref.h"
    return vft;
};
```

The `struct` is allocated with the required `size`, the pointers are defined based on the annotations in the source code. The included file is the output of the script. Plain simple

### The source files

There are a few files:

- main.c is above
- vft.h is the header
- vfc.c has

```
int     function_1(Packet*); 
int     function_2(Packet*);
int     function_3(Packet*);

VFT*    build_VFT(const unsigned);
VFT*    delete_VFT(VFT*);
int     callById(const Id, const VFT*);
```

as expected. Delete_VFT() is trivial. callById() is in fact a one-liner, just a call. but in the example is

```
int     callById(const Id id, const VFT* V)
{
    static Packet pck;
    pck.id = id;
    if( (unsigned) id >= V->nIds) return -1;
    if( V->fn[id] == NULL ) return -1;
    printf("\nWill call function for packet id %d\n", (int) id );
    return (*V->fn[(unsigned)id])(&pck);
};
```

Since this code is not operational a packet is built online with just the `Id`. And the corresponding parser function is called.

This was not extensively tested. I just cut and paste from places here. Compiled just under gcc 9.3 using this `makefile`

```
all:  main 

clear: 
    rm -f main *.o
    $(shell ./build_ref.sh ref.h from vft.c using "vft->fn")

main: main.o vft.o
    cc -o main main.o vft.o

main.o: main.c
    cc -c main.c

vft.o: vft.c vft.h
    cc -c vft.c

vft.c: vft.h
```

#### The table for this example

It is just a table after all...

```
vft->fn [ 1 ] =  function_1 ;
vft->fn [ 12 ] =  function_2 ;
vft->fn [ 22 ] =  function_2 ;
vft->fn [ 2 ] =  function_2 ;
vft->fn [ 149 ] =  function_3 ;
vft->fn [ 0 ] =  function_3 ;
vft->fn [ 3 ] =  function_3 ;
```

#### all files

Below is a single file with all text. If you find useful I can post a link on github

```
All files:

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////1: vft.h

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t Id;

typedef struct
{
    Id      id;
    void*   data;

}   Packet;

typedef int (*Packet_care)(Packet*);

typedef struct
{
    unsigned     nIds;
    Packet_care* fn;

}   VFT;   

int     function_1(Packet*); 
int     function_2(Packet*);
int     function_3(Packet*);

VFT*    build_VFT(const unsigned);
VFT*    delete_VFT(VFT*);
int     callById(const Id, const VFT*);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////2: vft.c

#include "vft.h"

int     function_1(Packet* p) // @packet-id 1
{
    printf("Hi from function_1(), id is %d\n", (int) p->id);
    return 0;
};

// function_2 @packet-id 12
// function_2 @packet-id 22
int     function_2(Packet* p) // @packet-id 2
{
    printf("Hi from function_2(), id is %d\n", (int) p->id);
    return 0;
};

// function_3 @packet-id 149
// function_3 @packet-id 0
int     function_3(Packet* p) // @packet-id 3
{
    printf("Hi from function_3(), id is %d\n", (int) p->id);
    return 0;
};

VFT*    build_VFT(const unsigned size)
{
    VFT* vft = (VFT*) malloc(sizeof(VFT));
    vft->nIds = size;
    vft->fn = (Packet_care*) malloc ( size*sizeof(Packet_care*) );
    for( int i=0; i<size; i+= 1) *(vft->fn + i) = NULL;
    #include "ref.h"
    return vft;
};

VFT*    delete_VFT(VFT* vft)
{
    if ( vft == NULL ) return NULL;
    if ( vft->nIds == 0) return NULL;
    free( vft->fn );
    free( vft );
    return NULL;
};

int     callById(const Id id, const VFT* V)
{
    static Packet pck;
    pck.id = id;
    if( (unsigned) id >= V->nIds) return -1;
    if( V->fn[id] == NULL ) return -1;
    printf("\nWill call function for packet id %d\n", (int) id );
    return (*V->fn[(unsigned)id])(&pck);
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////3: main.c

#include "vft.h"
int main(void)
{
    VFT* vft = build_VFT(150);
    printf("\nProcessing packets...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i += 1)
        printf("function returned %d for id %d\n",
            callById( (Id) i, vft), i);

    callById(149,vft);
    callById(22,vft);
    callById(12,vft);
    vft = delete_VFT(vft);
    return 0;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////4: t.awk.sh

BEGIN       { found = 0 }
/@packet-id/{ 
        fName =  $2
        if ( fName ~ /\(/ )
        {
            fName = gensub( /(.+)\((.+)/, "\\1", 1, $2)
        }
        ref = 0
        for( i = 3; i < NF; i++)
        {
            if ($i ~ "@packet-id" )
            {
                ref = i+1
                i = NF + 1
            }
        }
        print ARRAY, "[", $ref, "] = ", fName, ";"
        found = found + 1
    }
END {   exit found    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////5: build_ref.sh

awk -v ARRAY=${5} -f t.awk.sh ${3} > ${1} 

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////6: makefile

all:  main 

clear: 
    rm -f main *.o
    $(shell ./build_ref.sh ref.h from vft.c using "vft->fn")

main: main.o vft.o
    cc -o main main.o vft.o

main.o: main.c
    cc -c main.c

vft.o: vft.c vft.h
    cc -c vft.c

vft.c: vft.h

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////7: ref.h for the example

vft->fn [ 1 ] =  function_1 ;
vft->fn [ 12 ] =  function_2 ;
vft->fn [ 22 ] =  function_2 ;
vft->fn [ 2 ] =  function_2 ;
vft->fn [ 149 ] =  function_3 ;
vft->fn [ 0 ] =  function_3 ;
vft->fn [ 3 ] =  function_3 ;
```